# `(kill-line 0)` kills physical line even with global-visual-line-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I define `backward-kill-line` like this.

```
(defun backward-kill-line ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-line 0))
```

And I'm using `global-visual-line-mode`.

`kill-line` kills visual line, but this `backward-kill-line` kills physical line.
How can I change `backward-kill-line` that kills only visual line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kill-line` still kills physical lines even in Visual Line mode. However the key `C-k` is rebound to `kill-visual-line`.

Emacs has no `backward-kill-line` command, but you may have picked one up somewhere. If you want a function that kills the visual line, either make a `backward-kill-visual-line` function, or use the following combined function which kills the visual line if in visual line mode and the physical line otherwise.

```
(defun backward-kill-visual-line (arg)
  "Kill ARG visual lines backward."
  (interactive "p")
  (funcall (if visual-line-mode #'kill-visual-line #'kill-line)
           (- 1 arg)))
```